# box changeing size when hovering

Tags: css, hover

So, i`m trying to make a box to expand a bit in all 4 directions when hovering over it. But for now it only expands to the right and bottom.

Thats what i have tried for now:

```
.boydiv:hover{
width: 150px;
height: 250px;
background-color: #436eb1;

.boydiv{
width: 120px;
position: fixed;
top: 300px;
left: 150px;
border: solid;
border-color: black;
border-radius: 12px;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
transition-duration: 0.2s;
transition-timing-function: linear;
transition-delay: 0s;
animation-name: boydiv;
animation-duration: 0s;
```

Answer (score 1):

On the :hover state you do not change the top and left position. Therefore the top left corner of the element will grow in the other direction.

What you can do is either use flex-box (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or a simpler solution is to position the object at its center position and then use "transform: translate(-50%, -50%)" to recenter it. So:

```
.boydiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 410px;
    left: 210px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 220px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.boydiv:hover {
    width: 150px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but after implementing the `transform` it didnt change the size at all.

Comment: Have you closed your brackets? Also, in my example, I forgot to put a "." before the classname.

Comment: Yea, brackets are closed `transform: translate (-50%, -50%);` <- That`s what i used to replace all the transition things

Comment: Didn`t work neither. Might need to mention that its a box in a box (if that matters). It jut puts my box i want to edit a bit higher/lower when using the transform thing.

Comment: I need more information on why it is not working (does the color change for example). Could you create a jsfiddle with everything you have (except confidential information) so I could have a look at it?

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle, see if it works: https://jsfiddle.net/wfue87d3/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. You can use a `flex` container like this, for example:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.boydiv:hover{
width: 200px;
height: 180px;
background-color: #436eb1;
}

.boydiv{
width: 120px;
height: 100px;
border: solid;
border-color: black;
border-radius: 12px;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
transition: all .2s linear;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="boydiv"></div>
```

Comment: Tried that too but it just kinda threw everything around the page.